# Why does the order keep changing when appending repeated results from a json iteration?

Tags: jquery, append

I first get a JSON playlist of videos. I then get JSON information on each video id that was provided in the playlist. From each video information JSON I want to list the video's thumbnail url in the "#container" div.

My issue is that the order of thumbnails changes every time I hit the "Get JSON data" button. I looked in the console and the individual video JSON is always queried in the same order, it's just that when I post information from that JSON it's not in order.

What gives?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    //$('p').remove();
        $.getJSON("https://api.dailymotion.com/playlist/xy4h8/videos",function(result){

            $.each(result.list, function (index, value) {
            //  console.log(value.id); 
                $.getJSON("https://api.dailymotion.com/video/"+value.id+"?fields=id,title,thumbnail_medium_url",function(resulted){
                    $("#container").append(resulted.thumbnail_medium_url + "<br />"); // THIS IS THE BIT ALWAYS OUT OF ORDER
                }); // use id of each object in list to get next json
            }); // for each of the list object within the playlist result obj

        }); // get playlist json
    }); // button click
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous. For every element in `result.list`, you send out an AJAX request with a callback that fires whenever the request finishes, which has no guaranteed order at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because inside a each loop you are making ajax call. So all request go almost simultaneously. And depending on the response time taken by each ajax call values are appended on container. So whose response will come first it will be added first. Thats why order is different all the time.

Queue all your ajax request if you want every time same order. This may help you to keep all ajax request on queue. See the third example "Queueing something like Ajax Calls"
http://learn.jquery.com/effects/uses-of-queue-and-dequeue/

Answer (score 0):

The `$.getJSON()` function is [just a shortcut](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for the `$.ajax()` function with the data type set to `json`.  If you look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the jQuery.ajax() function, you will see that it is set to asynchronous by default, which means that it may happen at any time and may not be in a specified order.  You can remedy the problem by doing a straight `jQuery.ajax()` with `async: false` and `dataType: 'json'`.